# Applying rateit jquery plugin to a select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I have the following select form element, and I want to apply the [rateit jquery plugin](http://www.radioactivethinking.com/rateit/example/example.htm) to it.

```
<select class="test" id="Rating" name="Rating">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
```

and I am trying to apply the plugin using `$("select.test").rateit();`, but despite fireQuery showing data attached the the select element that, no effect is made and I am still left with a select box, and not a line of stars.

**EDIT**

CSS File is included

[Here is the page in question](http://waggleb.com/12454874521145474-2/?Type=CDA1C2A0-0BDC-47FD-B08D-BEDF8A6006DB&Id=D60A3983-8F2A-4152-885E-2743B1CCED13)

Comment: You need to include the css file. Doesn't work still? Need to see your demo, it's only guess work without it.

Comment: Edited answer to reflect current situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the plugin wrong. See very simple example: http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/ZuJ2k/

The `select` has to be there, but you still have to reference the `div` when you call the plugin: `$('div#rating2').rateit();`

The div then has a reference to the `select` with a data attribute: `data-rateit-backingfld="select#Rating"`

**edit**
Actually it looks like you're not using the plugin at all? Where do you call the plugin?

**edit**
This is your code:

```
rateItDiv = $('<div class="rateit" data-rateit-backingfld="#Rating"></div>');
$("div#ReviewInputZone select.test").after(rateItDiv);
$('div#rateit').rateit();
```

On the last line, you reference `div#rateit`, but that `div` doesn't exist. You just created a `div.rateit`, not a `div#rateit`. Change either of those to the other, and it should work. I'd keep the `#` because that's slightly faster (but you'd have to be sure there's only one of these rateit dropdowns on a page).

So the new first line:

```
rateItDiv = $('<div id="rateit" class="rateit" data-rateit-backingfld="#Rating"></div>');
```

**edit**
Also, you can test it before you change any code. Just open your Javascript console (Firebug in FF or Developer tools in Chrome) and type: `jQuery('div.rateit').rateit();`

Comment: have attempted to make those changes, still not getting it!!

Comment: Awesome, that's worked. But now I am struggling with implementing 5 stars without a reset/delete button. Script is updated if you fancy casting your eye over it. Many thanks for help thus far!